# Granting SELECT permission on table still does not apply

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-grant, external-tables

I have created an external table on my db with ADMIN user.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext.mytable
(...)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [DB in another server],SCHEMA_NAME = N'dbo',OBJECT_NAME = N'otherTable')
```

My external tables are in schema `ext`. Only administrator can see tables in `ext` schema.

Then I create a VIEW that SELECT rows from the external table:

```
CREATE VIEW live.MyView AS SELECT * FROM ext.mytable
```

My user own the schema `live`.

Then I granted SELECT permissions on that table to my user.

```
 GRANT SELECT ON ext.mytable TO user_service
```

Finally I connect to db with `user_service` and I try to query the table:

SELECT * FROM ext.mytable

But I get this error:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'mytable', database 'insights-dwh', schema 'ext'.
```

The table in datasource referenced by the external table own to another user in a different server. So the admin who created the external table is different from the table referenced.

What's wrong in granting permissions? How can I solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: When you say "The table in datasource referenced by the external table own to another user in a different server" does that mean that `ext.mytable` is actually a view (materialized or not) to a different table on a different database?

Comment: yes.. i have an EXTERNAL TABLE.... and then a VIEW with JOINS, conditions, ... etc on that table

Comment: You'll need to mention that on your Question. I'd probably mention the details on that external table. As in the select and perhaps the database link used. Are you able to log into "ext" as "user_service" and select from it?

Comment: changed... I hope is clearer now... I cannot do a SELECT on the `ext` table.. and I do not see the table.. I want `user_service` cannot see the ext table but I would like he can select from it via a view

Comment: Can the user that you used to make the grant see the table?

Comment: Yes... he is the same user who created the external table

Comment: yes, there is an external data source, but not a linked server...